# CSS extend one element of a group of DIV

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm currently trying to get an element (div) stretching itself over the free space of a parent element while respecting the size of other elements on its level. I found some solutions and tried most of them but I couldn't get it to work. I suspect this is because of the cms I'm working with which - when telling it to make a set of columns the same height - changes the parent display-style to table-cell. So... here is an image of what I'm trying to archive.

[image: stretch]

As said, the CMS changes the blue container to display: table-cell to stretch it over the whole area and make all columns in a row the same height. Inside of this blue container are the elements I can control. These are up to four div (white/green) inside of a parent div (yellow). The white div are dynamic and not always present and the green one needs to stretch over the whole vertical space no matter which of the white elements are present.

And idea how to accomplish that? I tried a lot of answers about this topic but they didnt work.. I think that's maybe due to the fact that the blue container is a table-cell?

edit: Here is what I got so far.

```
<div id="box_wrap">
    <div class="box_title">
        Title
    </div>
    <div class="box_image">
        Image
    </div>
    <div class="box_content">
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="box_more">
        Read More
    </div>
</div>
```

All of this is in a container provided by the CMS itself which has the attibute display: table-cell.

```
#box_wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    }

.box_content {
    display: flex;
    flex: 2;
}
```

I think the problem might be that the container provided my the CMS has no defined height. If I give my #box_wrap a fixed height manually then the div in it will work as they should. I also tried height: auto and height: 100% for the #box_wrap and it doesn't work. Again, probably because the parent has no defined height, no? That is the last thing that I need to solve. The #box_wrap needs to stretch over the vertical, currently it only extends as far as it needs to cover the content.

I also noticed that the first image I provided wasn't 100% accurate so I updated it.

Comment: What do you have so far? Please provide some markup.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself? Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and any relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the insufficient post. I will provide what I got so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this to allow the `.box_content` to grow (i.e. become higher) and the others not:

```
.box_title,
.box_image,
.box_image  {
  flex-grow: 0;
}
.box_content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

In addition, you should apply `height: 100%` to `#box_wrap`, but for that you also need `height: 100%` on `body` and `html` to have a reference for the height of `#box_wrap`.  So, to sum up:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#box_wrap {
  height: 100%;
}
```

You also might want to add...

```
body { 
  padding: 10px; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

...to get that distance between the edge of the screen and your container as it's shown in your image.

Comment: Thanks Johannes. I will give it a try, but so far the box_content-Container works as intended. It is the #box_wrap (yellow) that doesn't stretch over its parents height.